# How to send a location to a phone on Google maps programatically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps has a feature called "Send to phone" where it lets you send a notification in Google maps to your phone from your computer.

Is there a way to trigger that notification programatically using a Google API to send a location to your phone inside of Google maps. I will only be doing this on one computer and it's associated to the same Google account as the Android phone in question.

I want to avoid sending a link as that adds one more point of failure for non technical users.

Reading the Google maps API, I was not able to find something like that..

Thank you